# Elm package install fails with 'Prelude.read: no parse'

Tags: elm

I am unable to install any modules or initialize new packages with Elm-package.exe
It was working fine for awhile when suddenly it began to throw with this error:

```
Error: failed with 'Prelude.read: no parse' when sending request to   <http://package.elm-lang.org/all-packages?elm-package-version=0.16&since=elm-package.exe: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I am able to access this url through my browser, through my console and I've also added a firewall rule to allow elm-package.exe after it stopped working, just in case.

**Update**: The repl also fails with the same error on every expression:

```
User > elm repl
---- elm repl 0.16.0 -----------------------------------------------------------
:help for help, :exit to exit, more at <https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-repl>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 1 + 2
failed with 'Prelude.read: no parse' when sending request to
<http://package.elm-lang.org/all-packages?elm-package-version=0.16&since=elm-make: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Comment: There were some connection issues to http://package.elm-lang.org/ yesterday but it's OK now. Do you still have the problem?

Comment: @pdamoc yes the issue is still here. Tried an uninstall and re-install of Elm .16 with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elm Package uses a 'last updated' file to store a date and time which it refers to every time it runs. The problem lay in the file becoming corrupt somehow, probably by an IDE or IDE plugin that tries to incorporate elm-package.exe.

Deleting the elm folder in c:\users\user\roaming\elm solved the problem.